# How to detect inherited attributes in PHP 8

Tags: php, inheritance, attributes, php-8

In the following code, there are 2 attribute classes:

- `Attr` that need a string.
- `SubAttr` that extends `Attr` and use a predefined value.

```php
#[Attribute(Attribute::TARGET_METHOD)]
class Attr 
{
    public function __construct(
        public string $value,
    ) 
    { }
}

class SubAttr extends Attr 
{
    public function __construct() { 
        parent::__construct("Predefined value");
    }
}
```

Testing:

I expected `ReflectionMethod::getAttributes()` to get `Attr` data from `SubAttr` for `bar()` method.

```php
class Example 
{
    #[Attr("something")]
    public function foo() { }

    #[SubAttr]
    public function bar() { }
}

$method = new ReflectionMethod(Example::class, 'foo');
var_dump(count($method->getAttributes(Attr::class)) == 1); // TRUE

$method = new ReflectionMethod(Example::class, 'bar');
var_dump(count($method->getAttributes(Attr::class)) == 1); // FALSE
// How to get SubAttr attribute?
```

How `getAttributes()` can get inherited attributes ?
Is is necessary to get all attributes and check if any of them extends `Attr` ?

Comment: Slight error in the constructor of `Attr`: `public string $value` should be `string $value`?

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right. Weird. A public argument, that's new to me. Can't find it [in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php), but it could be there.

Comment: Found it: [Constructor Promotion](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.constructor.promotion). Oh, that's very handy, although a bit "covert". Remember reading that now....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get inherited attributes, we can use the constant **`ReflectionAttribute::IS_INSTANCEOF`** for the parameter `$flag` of `ReflectionClass::getAttributes()` method:

```php
$method->getAttributes(Attr::class, ReflectionAttribute::IS_INSTANCEOF)
```

Working program:

```php
#[Attribute(Attribute::TARGET_METHOD)]
class Attr {
    public function __construct(public string $value) 
    { }
}

class SubAttr extends Attr {
    public function __construct() { 
        parent::__construct("Predefined value");
    }
}

class Example 
{
    #[SubAttr]
    public function bar() { }
}

$method = new ReflectionMethod(Example::class, 'bar');
$attrs  = $method->getAttributes(Attr::class, ReflectionAttribute::IS_INSTANCEOF);

var_dump(count($attrs) == 1); // TRUE
```